# Faster way to access data than dict

Tags: python, list, performance, dictionary

I have a program that stores list of data with more than 90 keys in a dictionary like below:

```py
data = {
    'key0': 'abc',
    'key1': 'xyz',
    'key2': '0,1,2',
    'key3': -1,
    'key4': '15',
    'key5': '4.3',
    'key6': '1',
    'key7': '0',
    .
    .
    .
}
```

If a value does not exist for a key, it stores `-1` as value with type of `int`, all other existent values are type of `str`.

I have thousands of dictionaries like this stored in a list, and when I want to access a value, I access it with this function:

```py
KEYS_STR = (0, 1, )
KEYS_FLOAT = (5, )
KEYS_INT = (4, )
KEYS_LIST = (2, )

def get_key_value(data, key):
    index = list(data).index(key)
    value = data[key]

    if value == -1:
        return None
    else:
        if index in KEYS_STR:
            return str(value)
        elif index in KEYS_LIST:
            return [int(val) for val in value.split(',')]
        elif index in KEYS_FLOAT:
            if ',' in value:
                return float(value.split(',')[0])
            return float(value)
        elif index in KEYS_INT:
            try:
                if ',' in value:
                    return int(value.split(',')[0])
                return int(value)
            # Some fields may be hexadecimal
            except:
                if ',' in value:
                    return int(value.split(','), 16)
                return int(value, 16)
        else:
            if ',' in value:
                return bool(int(value.split(','),[0]))
            return bool(int(value))
```

```py
get_key_value(data, 'key1')
```

But this takes too much time since I call this function millions of times to access the values. Is there a faster, better way for storing my list of data?

Edit: It seems that turning a dictionary to a list over and over again for every get method call is too expensive, so I just moved the type decider thing into my dictionary initializer so they will be stored in the right type in my dictionary.

Comment: Converting the whole dictionary to a list over and over again is expensive nonsense.  Why don't you just create a second dictionary with the same keys that stores the "preferred type" of the item?  Better yet, why not just convert the dictionary to your desired types as soon as you create it?  Why keep it as strings?  That way, your function becomes a one-liner: `return data[key]`.

Comment: instead of storing -1 you could store None or omit the key all together if you use data.get(key) it returns None if the key doesn’t exist.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you! Appearently converting a dict to a list is really expensive. I stored my data in the right type beforehand, thus the runtime decreased by 40%.

Comment: @nickrl21 I can't actually omit the key because I need the index of the field to decide its type. If I omit the key, the indexes will be messed up.

Comment: @bhdrozgn, you keep indices for all the keys to decide the type to cast?? Why don't you cast every field when you create the dictionaries? That would be much more practical.

Comment: @cesarv Yes, now I am creating the dictionary with the right type as Tim Roberts suggested, instead of casting them to the right type when I call the getter method.